# How to install libxml2 version 2.9.0?

Tags: macos, libxml2, ruby-1.8.7, libxml-ruby

I am trying to install particular version of `libxml2`.
I used `brew search libxml2` but it seems there is only one result is available.

Brew is installing `libxml2-2.9.4` but need `libxml2-2.9.0` version so i tried to install by [source](http://%20http://archive.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs-museum/snapshot-20121101/blfs-20121102/general/libxml2.html) and followed the instructions given there,

But I am getting some exception:

```
onfig.status: executing libtool commands
rm: libtoolT: No such file or directory
Done configuring
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in include
Making all in libxml
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in .
  CC     SAX.lo
  CC     entities.lo
  CC     encoding.lo
encoding.c:491:26: warning: cast from 'const unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:573:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:729:26: warning: cast from 'const unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:815:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
  CC     error.lo
  CC     parserInternals.lo
  CC     parser.lo
parser.c:13492:43: warning: passing 'const xmlChar *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different
      sign [-Wpointer-sign]
        hdlr = xmlFindCharEncodingHandler(doc->encoding);
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/libxml/encoding.h:175:42: note: passing argument to parameter 'name' here
        xmlFindCharEncodingHandler      (const char *name);
                                                     ^
1 warning generated.
  CC     tree.lo
  CC     hash.lo
  CC     list.lo
  CC     xmlIO.lo
  CC     xmlmemory.lo
xmlmemory.c:328:9: warning: cast from 'char *' to 'MEMHDR *' (aka 'struct memnod *') increases required alignment from 1 to 8 [-Wcast-align]
    p = CLIENT_2_HDR(ptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xmlmemory.c:113:26: note: expanded from macro 'CLIENT_2_HDR'
#define CLIENT_2_HDR(a) ((MEMHDR *) (((char *) (a)) - RESERVE_SIZE))
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xmlmemory.c:434:9: warning: cast from 'char *' to 'MEMHDR *' (aka 'struct memnod *') increases required alignment from 1 to 8 [-Wcast-align]
    p = CLIENT_2_HDR(ptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xmlmemory.c:113:26: note: expanded from macro 'CLIENT_2_HDR'
#define CLIENT_2_HDR(a) ((MEMHDR *) (((char *) (a)) - RESERVE_SIZE))
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
  CC     uri.lo
  CC     valid.lo
  CC     xlink.lo
  CC     HTMLparser.lo
  CC     HTMLtree.lo
  CC     debugXML.lo
debugXML.c:2950:11: warning: comparison of array 'arg' equal to a null pointer is always false [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            if ((arg == NULL) || (arg[0] == 0))
                 ^~~    ~~~~
1 warning generated.
  CC     xpath.lo
xpath.c:4870:73: warning: passing 'xmlXPathFunction' (aka 'void (*)(struct _xmlXPathParserContext *, int)') to parameter of type 'void *' converts between void pointer and function
      pointer [-Wpedantic]
    return(xmlHashAddEntry2(ctxt->funcHash, name, ns_uri, XML_CAST_FPTR(f)));
                                                                        ^
./include/libxml/hash.h:56:29: note: expanded from macro 'XML_CAST_FPTR'
#define XML_CAST_FPTR(fptr) fptr
                            ^~~~
./include/libxml/hash.h:131:34: note: passing argument to parameter 'userdata' here
                                         void *userdata);
                                               ^
xpath.c:4951:24: warning: assigning to 'xmlXPathFunction' (aka 'void (*)(struct _xmlXPathParserContext *, int)') from 'void *' converts between void pointer and function pointer
      [-Wpedantic]
    XML_CAST_FPTR(ret) = xmlHashLookup2(ctxt->funcHash, name, ns_uri);
                       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xpath.c:12402:13: warning: comparison of constant 'XML_NAMESPACE_DECL' (18) with expression of type 'xmlXPathTypeVal' is always false [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
                        if (type == XML_NAMESPACE_DECL)
                            ~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xpath.c:13535:41: warning: assigning to 'xmlXPathFunction' (aka 'void (*)(struct _xmlXPathParserContext *, int)') from 'void *' converts between void pointer and function pointer
      [-Wpedantic]
                    XML_CAST_FPTR(func) = op->cache;
                                        ^ ~~~~~~~~~
xpath.c:13562:31: warning: assigning to 'void *' from 'xmlXPathFunction' (aka 'void (*)(struct _xmlXPathParserContext *, int)') converts between void pointer and function pointer
      [-Wpedantic]
                    op->cache = XML_CAST_FPTR(func);
                              ^               ~~~~
In file included from xpath.c:185:
./trionan.c:194:1: warning: unused function 'trio_is_special_quantity' [-Wunused-function]
trio_is_special_quantity
^
./trionan.c:218:1: warning: unused function 'trio_is_negative' [-Wunused-function]
trio_is_negative
^
7 warnings generated.
  CC     xpointer.lo
  CC     xinclude.lo
  CC     nanohttp.lo
nanohttp.c:1526:38: warning: while loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
        while ( xmlNanoHTTPRecv(ctxt) > 0 ) ;
                                            ^
nanohttp.c:1526:38: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
1 warning generated.
  CC     nanoftp.lo
  CC     catalog.lo
  CC     globals.lo
  CC     threads.lo
threads.c:442:9: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_mutex_lock' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
    if (pthread_mutex_lock != NULL)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:442:9: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
    if (pthread_mutex_lock != NULL)
        ^
        &
threads.c:512:9: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_mutex_unlock' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
    if (pthread_mutex_unlock != NULL)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:512:9: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
    if (pthread_mutex_unlock != NULL)
        ^
        &
threads.c:866:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_once' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
        if ((pthread_once != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:866:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
        if ((pthread_once != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:867:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_getspecific' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_getspecific != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:867:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_getspecific != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:868:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_setspecific' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_setspecific != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:868:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_setspecific != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:869:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_key_create' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_key_create != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:869:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_key_create != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:870:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_key_delete' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_key_delete != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:870:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_key_delete != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:871:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_mutex_init' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_mutex_init != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:871:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_mutex_init != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:872:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_mutex_destroy' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_mutex_destroy != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:872:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_mutex_destroy != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:873:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_mutex_lock' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_mutex_lock != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:873:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_mutex_lock != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:874:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_mutex_unlock' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_mutex_unlock != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:874:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_mutex_unlock != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:875:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_cond_init' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_cond_init != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:875:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_cond_init != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:876:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_cond_destroy' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_cond_destroy != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:876:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_cond_destroy != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:877:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_cond_wait' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_cond_wait != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:877:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_cond_wait != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:878:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_equal' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_equal != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:878:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_equal != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:879:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_self' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_self != NULL) &&
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:879:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_self != NULL) &&
             ^
             &
threads.c:879:14: note: suffix with parentheses to turn this into a function call
            (pthread_self != NULL) &&
             ^
                         ()
threads.c:880:14: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_cond_signal' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
            (pthread_cond_signal != NULL)) {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:880:14: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
            (pthread_cond_signal != NULL)) {
             ^
             &
threads.c:916:35: warning: comparison of function 'pthread_key_delete' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
    if ((libxml_is_threaded)  && (pthread_key_delete != NULL))
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
threads.c:916:35: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
    if ((libxml_is_threaded)  && (pthread_key_delete != NULL))
                                  ^
                                  &
threads.c:918:20: error: expected expression
    once_control = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
                   ^
/usr/include/pthread.h:203:27: note: expanded from macro 'PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT'
#define PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT {_PTHREAD_ONCE_SIG_init, {0}}
                          ^
18 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [threads.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may already have fixed this but have you tried:

`xcode-select install`

Even if you've already done this I sometimes find I have to do this again for some reason I've yet to fathom!